# z-index stack system is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, z-index

I am creating a tour for a website. On each step of the tour, a lightbox appears displaying text, and sometimes I want elements of the site to get over the lightbox to make them clickable.

For this, I first defined a z-index of 1100 for the lightbox (class .tour-backdrop). Then, when an element has to be clickable the Javascript code adds a class on this element (.tour-step-backdrop), which set this element a relative position and a z-index of 1101.

However, the element is still appearing below the lightbox...
I am sure that the element pointed is correct (the css is changed, but seems to have no effect.)

What I am doing wrong ?

HTML :

```
<div id="adminmenuwrap">
<ul id="adminmenu" role="navigation">


    <li class="wp-first-item wp-not-current-submenu wp-menu-separator menu-top-first menu-top-last"><div class="separator"></div></li>
    <li class="wp-not-current-submenu wp-menu-separator"><div class="separator"></div></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_mypage menu-icon-マイページtop menu-top-first" id="toplevel_page_ac_admin_mypage">
    <a href='profile.php' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_mypage menu-icon-マイページtop menu-top-first" aria-haspopup="true"><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class='wp-menu-image'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/mypage.png" alt="" /></div><div class='wp-menu-name'>マイページTOP</div></a>
    <ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'><li class='wp-submenu-head'>マイページTOP</li><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='profile.php' class="wp-first-item"><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />ユーザーページ</a></li><li><a href='https:/autocoding.jp/zip/layertags.pdf'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />タグ一覧ダウンロード</a></li><li><a href='https:/autocoding.jp/demo/demo_psd.zip'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />デモＰＳＤダウンロード</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_project_list menu-icon-プロジェクト一覧" id="toplevel_page_ac_admin_project_list">
    <a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_project_list' class="wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_project_list menu-icon-プロジェクト一覧" ><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class='wp-menu-image'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/project.png" alt="" /></div><div class='wp-menu-name'>プロジェクト一覧</div></a></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_points menu-icon-ポイント・購入管理" id="toplevel_page_ac_admin_points"><a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_points_buy' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_points menu-icon-ポイント・購入管理" aria-haspopup="true"><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class='wp-menu-image'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/point.png" alt="" /></div><div class='wp-menu-name'>ポイント・購入管理</div></a>
    <ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'><li class='wp-submenu-head'>ポイント・購入管理</li><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_points_buy' class="wp-first-item"><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />変換ポイントの購入</a></li><li><a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_points_history'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />購入履歴</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_faq menu-icon-faq" id="toplevel_page_faq">
    <a href='faq' class="wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_faq menu-icon-faq" ><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class='wp-menu-image'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/faq.png" alt="" /></div><div class='wp-menu-name'>FAQ</div></a></li>
    <li class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_manual menu-icon-マニュアル" id="toplevel_page_ac_admin_manual"><a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_prepare' class="wp-has-submenu wp-not-current-submenu menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_manual menu-icon-マニュアル" aria-haspopup="true"><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class='wp-menu-image'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/manual.png" alt="" /></div><div class='wp-menu-name'>マニュアル</div></a>
    <ul class='wp-submenu wp-submenu-wrap'><li class='wp-submenu-head'>マニュアル</li><li class="wp-first-item"><a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_prepare' class="wp-first-item"><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />1.事前準備</a></li><li><a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_layout'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />2.レイアウト</a></li><li><a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_layertag'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/arrow.png" />3.レイヤータグ</a></li></ul></li>
    <li class="current menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_tour menu-icon-ツアーを開始する menu-top-last" id="toplevel_page_ac_admin_tour">
    <a href='admin.php?page=ac_admin_tour' class="current menu-top toplevel_page_ac_admin_tour menu-icon-ツアーを開始する menu-top-last" ><div class="wp-menu-arrow"><div></div></div><div class='wp-menu-image'><img src="http://local.autocoding/wp-content/plugins/autocoding-admin-angular/img/tour.png" alt="" /></div><div class='wp-menu-name'>ツアーを開始する</div></a></li></li></ul>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.tour-backdrop{
    background: black;
    z-index:  1100;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.tour-step-backdrop{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1101;
    background: inherit;
}
```

JS :

```
_pointedDOM = $(_tipsContent[_start+_currentTip].dom);
_pointedDOM.addClass('tour-step-backdrop');
```

RESULT :
http://puu.sh/gWcuH/71bd5fd268.png

EDIT: I solved this problem by creating the lightbox inside the menu containing the button. However
 I'm not sure that is the best solution so if you have a clue do not hesitate to inform everyone about it.

Comment: You may have a look at [this](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/07/17/troubleshooting-css/#article-z-index) article wich I found very intersting

Comment: try adding `position: absolute/relative/fixed` to your `.tour-backdrop` in CSS.

Comment: @empiric Thank you, I read this and I learnt a lot about z-index that I did not know before. I think my problem is concerning stacking context. I will try to find the property which change the stacking context.

Comment: @Sushovan I tried all sort of combinaisions for the position property of .tour-backdrop and .tour-step-backdrop elements, but did not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make its position as absolute as:

```
.tour-step-backdrop{
   position: absolute;
   z-index: 1101;
   background: inherit;
}
```